# setTimeout adding +1 to for loop "i" during elapsed time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 sequential or subordinates drop-down menus that could be either selected by the user ( which works fine ) or, in some instances, need to be selected via js.

I have set a timeout to give time to js to populate the first drop-down before the options are available to be selected in the sequence. It does not work otherwise.

The problem is that somehow during the elapsed time of the setTimeout, var "i" is being added of one, which throws off the script.

If I force "i" to be equal to zero in the case where I have only one input to consider, this will work fine. As this is dynamic and I cannot do that, I am looking on ways to stop this behavior.

The code below stops at the 2nd drop-down.

Is setTimeout the good solution in this case?
Thanks.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ctvid = <?php echo $ctvid ;?>;
    if(ctvid !=""){
    var info = <?php echo json_encode ($info);?>;
    for (var i=0;i<ctvid;i++){
        $('#brand' + i).val(info['brand_id'][i]).change();
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#model' + i).val(info['model_id'][i]).change(); 
            },500); 
    }   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` inside `setTimeout` is not captured inside a closure you need to create a closure by hand wrapping it in self executing anonymous function:

```
for (var i=0; i<ctvid; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#model' + i).val(info['model_id'][i]).change(); 
        },500); 
    })(i);
}
```

in your code `i` have always the last value for every element. [Example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3CHhJ/)

Comment: Thanks, jcubic and Elias. This worked for me, though for the 3rd drop-down I had to increase the time out to 1000,for some reason.  I have to say though that I do like the reasoning from hexblot and I will try his solution with a bit more time.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to avoid using time for such cases, since a slow connection would easily break it. In my opinion, it would be best in the "automatic" case to set a data property on an element ( eg body ) which you can check on the complete function of the select population.

To clarify:

on `functionB()` you populate selectB with elements, based on the selection of selectA. In that function, check if something is set. If so, use it to select an item in selectB, which you just populated, triggering selectC population.

Comment: Thanks hexblot. I understand the principle of checking for something to be set. As per knowing exactly what to check for is a bit too lofty for me. May be check if the value in #brand'+i is already what was supposed to be there?

Comment: I'd set something like `$('body').data('trigger-select', 'myval')`.So once the select is populated, check the value like this : `$('body').data('trigger-select') == ''`. If true, this was triggered by the user. If false, use the value and set to '' afterwards.

Comment: Isn't callbacks a way to handle this issue, ie, only execute the callback after the first function, in this case changing the first drop-down and then executing the callback to select one of the then available options?